# What do these signs mean League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I can guess, that they have something in common with wards.
But what is it? Can enemies see me thanks to it?

[image]

Comment: I don't remember all the details, but they show up right after an enemy ward expires and live on for some time. The purpose being to let you know that there *used* to be an enemy ward there (and that there very well might be more that you can't see).

Comment: I feel like this shouldn't be a separate answer so I'll write it as a comment: Use those indicators to your advantage! If you don't see many of them you know that your enemy has poor vision control which allows for more risky plays/invades.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are places where wards were placed that have since timed out. The ones with red over them were placed by the other team. Enemies cannot see you because of it, but can tell where wards were placed for a short time afterwards.

Note: the colored orb (blue/red) above the stone will fade over time before disappearing, giving you a general idea of how long ago it was warded.

source- personal experience. Also pictured below, a bunch of ward stones.

[image]

Comment: Also, the brighter the red, the more recently it has expired. Or, the duller the red, the more time has passed since it has expired

Comment: @GuyShapter, correct, ill add that in

Comment: They are called 'rubble' or 'ward debris', and was added in [patch 5.22](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-522-notes#patch-stealth-and-vision-wards), and changed in [patch 6.2](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-62-notes#patch-ward-debris)

Answer (score 4):

This is called "ward rubble" or "ward debris" and was added in [Patch 5.22](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-522-notes#patch-stealth-and-vision-wards).

> Upon death or expiration, wards leave behind Rubble. Rubble is team colored, lasts up to <s>5</s> 4 minutes, and appears as circles where the ward was when it was active.

It used to be 5 minutes, but this was changed in [Patch 6.2](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-62-notes#patch-ward-debris) to 4 minutes.

> - Brightly glows in the first 10% of its lifespan!
> - Stops emitting flames after 30% of its lifespan has passed!
> - Particle visibly changes and debris shrinks after 60% of its lifespan has passed!

These features allow you to see and keep track of where the each team wards and how long ago the wards expired. This is helpful, as you can see a newly expired ward and know that the enemy laner(s) won't see a gank coming.