# How long does the 'Ward remnants' stay?

Tags: league-of-legends

It's new this season, wards leave a remnant when they expire/are destroyed.

These remnants don't give the vision or anything. But they are to mark where a ward once was.

So how long does this remnant last?

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/303779/115693)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to patch [6.22 patch notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-62-notes#patch-ward-debris), they now last 240 seconds, down from 300 seconds previously.